# .each() inside another .each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm still learning jQuery and am wondering if there are other ways to put `.each()` inside another `.each()` function:

JavaScript:

```
$("ul").each(function(index){

    $("#uid" + index + " li").each(function(listItemIndex){

        var listItemWidth = $(this).width();
        var listItemPosition = listItemIndex * listItemWidth;

        if (listItemIndex > 0){
            $(this).css("left", listItemPosition + (10 * listItemIndex));
        };
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="uid0">
    <li>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </li>
    <li>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </li>
</ul>
<ul id="uid1">
    <li>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </li>
</ul>
<ul id="uid2">
    <li>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </li>
    <li>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </li>
    <li>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </li>
    <li>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
$("ul").each(function() {
    var ul = this;
    $(ul).children('li').each(function(listItemIndex) {
        if (listItemIndex > 0) {
            var listItemWidth = $(this).width();
            var listItemPosition = listItemIndex * (listItemWidth + 10);
            $(this).css("left", listItemPosition);
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: (Yes, I know it's over 2 years old now, doesn't matter). Code-only answers are generally not good because they do not explain **how** or **why** they improve upon the OP's code. Even a short explanation of what your solution does and why would be far better than no explanation at all.